# C# EdiFabric Exporting EDI 835 Files

Tags: c#, edi, edifabric

I'm trying to export an EDI 835 using ediFbaric 7.07 with 5010 class files.

However, the ISA segment is always writing out a ">" for segment ISA16:

```
return new S_ISA
{
  // Authorization Information Qualifier
  D_744_1 = "00",
  ...                    
  // Component Element Separator
  D_701_16 = ":"
};
```

`

The output always looks like this:
`ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*InsurerId*ZZ*ProviderId*170120*2049*^*00501*111111111*0*P*>~`

The offending character being the last element which has a value of ">", instead of the expected ":".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The component element separator is taken from the separator set you used to generate the message. If you hadn't used any then it loads the default for X12, which is, as you might have guessed, ">".

Setting it in the message is discarded for the purpose of not having a different separator there and in the separators set.

To work around this call GenerateEdi with a new separator set like this:

```
var defaultSeparators = Separators.DefaultX12();
var newSeparators = new Separators(defaultSeparators.Segment,
                '>', 
                defaultSeparators.DataElement, 
                defaultSeparators.RepetitionDataElement, 
                null);
var ediSegments = interchange.GenerateEdi(newSeparators);
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. I thought it might have been my lack of knowledge on the library/classes. Thanks again for the quick answer.